# pandas subplot title size in ipython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I plotted two plots side by side in an ipython notebook cell. But, I am having trouble changing the size of the title. I can change the size of the labels by adding the argument `fontsize = 20`. How do I change the title for `df` and `df2`.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize = (20,10))
df.plot('barh', title = 'Legal Collectible Answer Distribution', fontsize = 20, ax = axes[0])
df2.plot(kind = 'pie', autopct = '%1.0f%%', legend = False, title = 'Legal Collectible Answer Distribution', fontsize = 20, ax =axes[1])
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can change the size of an existing title on the Axes using `title.set_size()`

```
axes[0].title.set_size(40)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try breaking out the title property onto its own, something like this should work:

```
df.plot.title('Legal Collectible Answer Distribution', fontsize=20)
df2.plot.title('Legal Collectible Answer Distribution', fontsize=20)
```

and remove title from the plot commands, not sure why it's not working in line, but in a quick test it doesn't work inline for me either.

Comment: There is no property called title on pandas.DataFrame.plot, I don't know if it had it the past but it doesn't now.